# Index XML attributes along with plain text in CLucene

Tags: xhtml, indexing, document, payload, clucene

I've been able to compile the CLucene project on iOS and am currently trying to use it within my iOS application. I'm trying to index xhtml documents, and have been able to do that by extracting the text nodes out of those documents, and then index in lucene by concatenating them together, so as to all the text from one xhtml doc appears in a single Lucene document.

However, each text node of my xhtml document has custom attributes to it, so that when a search is made on the indexed text, I should be also be able to obtain the attribute associated with that text.

My xml data looks like:

```
<span data-value="/1/2/3">This is a sample text for this span</span>
<span data-value="/2/3/4">This is a example text for another span</span>
<span data-value="/3/4/5">Searching for this span text</span>
```

So when I search from the Lucene index for a word sample, then I should be able to retrieve the data-value attributed to the word Sample is associated. In the case above it will be data-value="/1/2/3".

The way I'm creating an index is by concatenating the data-value attribute and the text node field together, and then have it indexed by Lucene. This way, whenever my search results return, then it would also return the data-value attributed along with it. I can evaluate the attribute value, and at the time of searching will strip away this attribute from the display results altogether. However, this is not true for large text contained in a span text, where in the searched word(s) may be returned but the data-value attributes may not be part of the search results, which can further be stripped off while display.

However, I think this is not the optimal way of indexing XML attributes along with their text data.

I'd appreciate if someone can help me with the approach in order to index the relationship between the text and its attributes.

Update: I found that the tokens generated from the text can have payloads associated with them, so I'm thinking that if we can have the XML attribute built in as a payload for my entire string, which can be treated as a single token (if I don't analyze the text), can be useful for my purpose. I wanted to know if anyone can help me in figuring out if this is the right approach for my case. Many thanks for your help.

Thanks & regards,
Asheesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep all of XHTML text as one Lucene document, then payloads are probably the way to go.

An alternate approach is to create a document ID field (like "documentID:42" and a field denoting that this Lucene document is the whole document concatenated together (like "AllOfDocument:42"). This would let you index each text node individually and limit the attributes to just the attributes for that node, while still tying that text node to whole document. With that approach, you could put the attributes in their own field in the text node Lucene document rather than having to use payloads. Might be simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Mark. So what you're saying is that I should create two different fields in a single document, where in the first field (documentID:42) would correspond to just the attribute-value for a particular text-node, and the other field (AllOfDocument:42), would contain that particular text-node, so that there's a 1-1 mapping between the text node and it's attribute value. This way, I'd have as many number of fields for both in a singe lucene document, as the textnodes in the XHTML doc. Would this also mean that one xhtml document is equal to one lucene document.

Comment: Also to confirm, when you mean all of the XHTML text as one lucene document, you mean if I'd want to index all of the textnodes in a single XHTML document. Is that right? If yes, then yes I want to index  all of the text in the xhtml documents, and that each text node should be tied to its attribute value.

Comment: I had meant to index each text node individually as a Lucene document, while also indexing all text nodes from an XHTML file as a separate Lucene document that you tie together with the text node Lucene documents (because "documentID:42" and "allOfDocument:42" have the same value of 42.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Mark. Just wanted to make sure that I understand it correctly. So what you're saying is to have three different documents, where in every attribute for a text-node like data-value="/1/2/3" would go into its own field in a document, and then there would be another field with just the "This is a sample ..." text-node in another document, and then another document would just have the entire text containing (text1 text2 text3)? But don't you think it would be duplication of data? Also, what would be the search results for my word "Sample" that also needs to be highlighted?

Comment: Yes, you would duplicate documents. If your use case could handle having all of the attributes for an XHTML file together, you could create a field value for each attribute attached to a Lucene document for the whole XHTML file (and index only the whole XHTML file as a Lucene document) -- but you lose the link between the attribute and the individual text node.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Yes, I want to try this approach, but I guess payload is an optimal solution, but involves more work. I'm not sure if CLucene supports payload correctly. I was trying a unit test for testing payload but it's crashing, so I will have to dig a bit more in order to try to use the payload with CLucene. I also found that there isn't a payloadTermQuery method in CLucene, which is usually used to retrieve results for queries which have payloads built into them. Do you have any suggestions on using payloads?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24209/discussion-between-ash1977-and-mark-leighton-fisher)

Comment: Mark, I went ahead, and used the approach of adding every textnode, and its subsequent attribute into its own document, so that ways all my text nodes are now linked to their corresponding attributes. The only flip side is that there are a lot of documents, which contains just two fields (text node and its attribute), but given the requirement that I have I had to take this route. I'd still prefer to use payloads, but since I'm using CLucene, the payload support in it still not complete. I'd try the payload approach for sure though sometime later.